# How to filter on a Seq[PartialFunction]

Tags: scala

I have a list of business rules and multiple rules can apply to a given input.

```
type Input = …
type Output = …
type Rule = PartialFunction[Input, Output]
```

I want to write the method that compute all valid output. I've come up with this implementation :

```
def applyRules(i: Input, rules: Seq[Rule]) : Seq[Output] = {
  rules.flatMap(_.lift.apply(i))
}
```

Is there a better way ?

Comment: Yeah, that's how I would do it. You don't need to spell out `apply` btw:
`rules.flatMap(_.lift(i))`

Comment: `rules.flatMap(Seq(i).collect(_))` as an option, or `rules.flatMap(Some(i).collect(_))` (though I don't like `CanBuildFrom` magic)

Answer (score 0):

One proposed variant of your solution (which I'd say is satisfactory) involves filtering and then mapping over the filtered results. This works but involves two passes over the same collection, which for smaller collection can be good. We can, however, reach the same result with three possible further variants:

1. using the `collect` method: `rules.collect { case r if r.isDefinedAt(i) => r(i) }`
2. using the lazy `withFilter` instead of `filter`: `rules.withFilter(_.isDefinedAt(i)).map(_.apply(i))` or
3. using a `for` comprehension (semantically identical to the one above but perhaps more readable): `for (r <- rule if r isDefinedAt i) r(i)`

These solutions *may* produce slightly less garbage (each call to `lift` creates a new instance of a function object - [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/99a82be91cbb85239f70508f6695c6b21fd3558c/src/library/scala/PartialFunction.scala#L94) the [code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/99a82be91cbb85239f70508f6695c6b21fd3558c/src/library/scala/PartialFunction.scala#L220-L227)), however if the number of Rules is small I'm sure in most cases that's a non-issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `isDefinedAt` to check whether given `Input` can be applied to `Rule`:

```
scala> val pf: PartialFunction[Any, Int] = { case s: String => 42 }
pf: PartialFunction[Any,Int] = <function1>

scala> pf.isDefinedAt(10)
res0: Boolean = false

scala> pf.isDefinedAt("")
res1: Boolean = true
```

So you can do something like:

```
val validInputs = rules.filter(_.isDefinedAt(i))
val result = validInputs.map(i)
```

Also `PartialFunction` contains methods `applyOrElse, orElse, ...`, that might increase readability.

Please correct me if I misunderstood your problem.

Comment: Op's solution is better